# Determine all simple zero rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

A ring $R$ is simple if it has no ideals other than ${0}$ and $R$. A ring in which every product is zero is called a zero ring. Determine all simple zero rings.

I want to say that the only simple zero ring is ${0}$ as a subring of the integers, but I have a feeling that by the way the problem is worded there are more. How can I find other simple zero rings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in a zero ring, every subspaces is an0 ideal.

So the question is about determining all simple abelian groups; then you can endow them with theh zero product and make them simple zero rings.

Comment: I believe that all simple abelian groups are the cyclic groups of prime order. Is that correct? If so, can I just say that the simple zero rings are these groups with the zero product?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ $