# All simple rings are prime rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to prove that simple rings are prime rings?

I know to prove a simple ring $R$ is prime,we have take two ideals $I,J$ of $R$ (since $R$ is simple, $I,J\in \{ \{0\}, R \}$) and prove $IJ=0$, then $I= 0$ or $J= 0$.

If $IJ=0$,the case of $I= 0$ or $J= 0$ is easy, but the case $I=J=R$, I think $RR$ must not be zero (But why?)

(In my book definition $R$ might not have identity)

Comment: Could you let us know which book you are using? It seems to me that the statement is no longer true if our ring is not unital.

Comment: I think, in texts discussing rings without identity, the condition $R^2\neq\{0\}$ or even $R^2=R$ is used as a substitute condition for the missing identity.

Comment: In fact, I'm doing proof of something else, if the statement true, my proof is done.
And the statement I find it on Prime ring@wiki

Comment: In my text book(A First Course in Abstract Algebra,John B. Fraleigh), the definition of ring not necessarily have unit but it is not define that ring $R$ must $R^2 \neq \{0\}$ or $R^2=R$

Comment: @Lee Jacobson might have a notion of prime ring without identity in one of his texts. You could check there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (not necessarily commutative) ring $R$ is called a prime ring if for any two two-sided ideals $I,J \subseteq R$, $IJ=\{0\}$ implies $I=\{0\}$ or $J=\{0\}$.

On the other hand, a (not necessarily commutative) ring $R$ is called simple if $R\neq \{0\}$ and $\{0\},R$ are the only two-sided ideals in $R$.

We now want to prove that all simple rings are prime rings. This means we want to show that if we take any two two-sided ideals $I,J\subseteq R$ with $IJ=\{0\}$, then $I=\{0\}$ or $J=\{0\}$. As $R$ is simple, the only two-sided ideals are $\{0\},R$. Now, if $I=\{0\}$ or $J=\{0\}$, then there is nothing to prove. The only case that is left to check is $I=R=J$. In this case $IJ=RR$. Now we might be a bit concerned what $RR$ actually is and rightfully so. If $R$ was unital, then $RR=R\neq \{0\}$ and we would be done.

However, if you are not assuming that $R$ is unital, then things can go wrong. Consider the following example. Pick $R=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with the standard addition and the multiplication given by
$$ n\cdot m =0 $$
for all $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. This forms a (non-unital) ring (as $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, +)$ is an abelian group, we are only required to check associativity of the multiplication and distributivity, but this holds as $(n\cdot m)\cdot l  =0 =  n\cdot (m\cdot l)$ and similarly for distributivity). In this ring we have $RR=\{0\}$, but $R\neq \{0\}$ and so this ring is not a prime ring, but it is simple (the only two non-empty subsets are $\{0\}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and they both form ideals).

The moral of this story is that for the statement to hold true we need to assume that $RR\neq \{0\}$.

Note that the family of rings where this fails is not particularly large. It must be of the form $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}, +)$ as an abelian group (for $p$ prime) and the multiplication is just zero. See here [Determine all simple zero rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775574/determine-all-simple-zero-rings?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you! Your response is very clear. And thank your for editing my post!

Comment: @Lee Glad that I could help. I must admit that I only realized halfway through my answer that the statement is not true in general. In my defense I am not an algebraist and rings with $RR=\{0\}$ is something that I never use :)